# Ansible facts discovery returns some values as empty

Tags: ansible, ansible-playbook

I have a very simple script in `/etc/ansible/facts.d` which is used to discover the local SSL certs on a host. This is the code:

```
#!/bin/sh

echo "{
  \"testkey\": \"testvalue\",
  \"crt\": \"$(/usr/bin/base64 -w 0 /etc/kubernetes/pki/apiserver.crt)\",
  \"key\": \"$(/usr/bin/base64 -w 0 /etc/kubernetes/pki/apiserver.key)\"
}"
```

When I run it myself with `$> /etc/ansible/facts.d/apiserver_ssl_facts.fact` it outputs all the values as expected. But when Ansible runs it only the `testkey` has a value, while the others are an empty string `""`:

```
ansible@bastion-1:~/ansible$ ansible -m setup <host> -a "filter=ansible_local"
<host> | SUCCESS => {
    "ansible_facts": {
        "ansible_local": {
            "apiserver_ssl_facts": {
                "crt": "", 
                "key": "", 
                "testkey": "testvalue"
            }
        }
    }, 
    "changed": false
}
```

Running Ansible in very verbose with `-vvvv` does not show any errors.

Comment: Does ansible user has access to those files?

Comment: @KonstantinSuvorov douh, you're right, that's it. if you want you can post it as answer, then i'll accept

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer from the comments: there is a permission issue, so the ansible user can't access cert files.